# how does bagof features work in MATLAB?

Tags: graphs, machine-learning

I tried to use machine learnign in matlab using bagoffeatures to captures features and teach the code betwee two types of plots. However, bagofFeatures could not detect ant features.
this is my plot:
[image]

How does bagofFeatures work? and would work on my plot if I changed the color og point depending on their high?

Comment: Questions about a particular tool, library, or programming language are off-topic here, so asking us to explain how some aspect of Matlab works is off-topic here.

Comment: does not computer science include programming? where should I take my question?